# Debugging Java get list of objects and local variables

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

Is there any way to get a list of all current objects and local variables when debugging a java program? Seems JDB doesn't offer such functionality. I only can inspect vars and objects if I know the name of them.

My aim is to step through any line of code from the beginning while being able to see at any time which objects live in memory and which local variables does my current method have.

Answer (score 3):

The command for listing the local variables is `locals`.

If you launch a `jdb` session and type `help`, it says:

```
locals                    -- print all local variables in current stack frame
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I only had a look at the [oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html)

Comment: `javac -g Xxx.class` first or you will get `Local variable information not available.  Compile with -g to generate variable information`.